# Analytic Solution to the Differential equation $(1-t^2)x'' + tx' - x = 0$.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I am looking to solve the following problem:

Consider the differential equation,

$$(1-t^2)x'' + tx' - x = 0$$

(a) Find a power series expansion about t = 0 for a general solution to the differential equation. Your answer should include a general formula for the coefficients.

(b) Solve the IVP $$(1-t^2)x'' + tx' - x = 0, x(0) = -1, x'(0) = 2$$

I have come to a dead end on this problem myself after my work and solution shown below;

$$x(t) =  \sum_{n=0}^\infty a_nt^n$$
$$x'(t) =  \sum_{n=1}^\infty a_nnt^{n-1}n$$
$$x''(t) =  \sum_{n=2}^\infty a_nn(n-1)t^{n-2}$$

Subsituting into the differential equation and simplifying gave:

$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty [a_{n+2}(n+2)(n+1) - a_nn(n-1)]t^n = 0$$

Since $t^n > 0$, we must have

$$a_{n+2}(n+2)(n+1) - a_nn(n-1) = 0 $$

This gives the recursive sequence:

$$a_{n+2} = \frac{a_nn(n-1)}{(n+2)(n+1)}$$

I am stuck here and am not sure how to proceed with solving the rest of the problem. I am looking for a solution to the initially stated problem so that I can compare my work to it and learn from it. As a note, I suspect my formula for the recursive sequence is incorrect since it terminates, although I am not sure.

Comment: Choose initial conditions, say, $a_0 = 1$.

Comment: I'm not sure I see how this would help solve the problem.

Comment: ... and you will get factorials in the numerator and the denominator (that will in fact almost cancel): $a_{n+2}=\dfrac{1}{(n+1)(n+2)}a_0$.

Comment: $a_0$ cannot be chosen. It must be solved for as stated in the problem.

Comment: The initial conditions are stated directly to the right of the ODE.

Comment: Sorry, I did not see the third incarnation of the ODE, the first two do not have initial conditions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The coefficient iteration is
$$
t^n:\, 0=(n+2)(n+1)a_{n+2}-n(n-1)a_n+na_n-a_n=(n+1)(n+2)a_{n+2}-(n-1)^2a_n
$$
For the first powers this gives
\begin{align}
2a_2&=a_0\\
6a_3&=0\\
12a_4&=a_2\\
20a_5&=4a_3=0\\
30a_6&=9a_4
\end{align}
so the general solution starts as
$$
x(t)=x'(0)t+x(0)\left(1+\frac12t^2+\frac1{24}t^4+\frac1{80}t^6+...\right)
$$

Answer (score 1):

$$
t^n: 0 = (n+2)(n+1)a_{n+2} - n(n-1)a_n + na_n - a_n = (n+1)(n+2)a_{n+2}-(n-1)^2a_n \Leftrightarrow
$$

$$
a_{n+2} = \frac{(n-1)^2}{(n+2)(n+1)}a_n:
$$

$$
\begin{aligned}
a_0 &= -1 \\
a_1 &= 2 \\
a_2 &= \frac{(-1)^2}{2\cdot 1}a_0 = -\frac{1^2}{1\cdot 2} \\
a_3 & = 0 \\
a_4 &= \frac{1^2}{4\cdot 3}a_2 = -\frac{1^2}{1\cdot 2\cdot 3\cdot 4} = -\frac{1^2}{4!} \\
a_5 &= \frac{2^2}{5\cdot 4}a_3 = 0 \\
a_6 &= \frac{3^2}{6 \cdot 5}a_4 = -\frac{1^2\cdot 3^2}{4!\cdot 5\cdot 6} = -\frac{1^2\cdot 3^2}{6!} = -\frac{\prod\limits_{j = 1}^{3-1}(2j-1)^2}{(2\cdot 3)!}\\
a_7 &= \frac{4^2}{7\cdot 6}a_5 = 0 \\
a_8 &= \frac{5^2}{8 \cdot 7}a_6 = -\frac{1^2\cdot 3^2 \cdot 5^2}{6!\cdot 7\cdot 8} = -\frac{1^2\cdot 3^2\cdot 5}{8!} = -\frac{\prod\limits_{j = 1}^{4-1}(2j-1)^2}{(2\cdot 4)!} \\
a_9 &= \frac{6^2}{9\cdot 8}a_7 = 0 \\
a_{10} &= \frac{7^2}{10 \cdot 9}a_8 = -\frac{1^2\cdot 3^2 \cdot 5^2 \cdot 7^2}{8!\cdot 9\cdot 10} = -\frac{1^2\cdot 3^2\cdot 5 \cdot 7^2}{10!} = -\frac{\prod\limits_{j = 1}^{5-1}(2j-1)^2}{(2\cdot 5)!} \\
&\ldots \ldots \ldots \ldots \ldots \ldots \ldots \ldots \ldots \ldots \ldots \ldots \ldots \ldots \ldots \ldots \ldots \ldots \ldots \ldots \ldots\\
a_{2k-1} &= 0, \quad k \geq 2 \\
a_{2k} &= -\frac{\prod\limits_{j = 1}^{k-1}(2j-1)^2}{(2k)!}, \quad k \geq 2
\end{aligned}
$$

$$
x(t) = -1 + 2t -\frac{1}{2}t^2 - \sum_{k = 2}^{+\infty}\frac{\prod\limits_{j = 1}^{k-1}(2j-1)^2}{(2k)!}t^{2k}
$$